# Customize djoser logout

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, djoser

Djoser have `auth/token/logout/` end point to logout and it destroys the token.
Now I wanted to do more when logout so I have inherited the `TokenDestroyView` of djoser:

```
from djoser.views import TokenDestroyView
from djoser import utils

class UserLogoutView(TokenDestroyView):

    def post(self, request):
        attendance = Attendance.objects.get(user=request.user, check_in_date=localdate(now()))
        attendance.check_out = localdate(now())
        attendance.save()
        print(attendance)
        print(attendance.check_out)
        utils.logout_user(request)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Now I have my own endpoint as `users/v1/logout/` 
I get the `200 52` response but it is not deleting the token and even it is not going inside the post method.

Where am I missing ?

Comment: Probably you have to register your view in `urls.py` instead of the default one.

Comment: @KamilNiski I have registered my `UserLogoutView` in urls.py and the corresponding url is `users/v1/logout`